# Can't center this

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I try to center the nav paragraphs, it won't center. I have tried a lot of things now, but can't find the result.

Here is my CSS :

```css
header {
  background: #444444;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: height 600ms 0s ease;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#head {
  font-family: quicksand;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 82px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navs {
  font-family: quicksand;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: quicksand
}

#left {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

Here is my HTML :
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="head">Resume - Mathias Nicolajsen</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <a href="diagonaler.html"><strong><p class="navs" id="left">Projecter</p></strong></a>
  <strong><p class="navs">Omkring mig</p></strong>
</nav>
<p>Lavet af Mathias Nicolajsen</p>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: did you try **margin:0 auto**  with **float:none**

Comment: can you please share you html snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `text-align: center;` to `nav { }` to center the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  background: #444444;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: height 600ms 0s ease;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#head {
  font-family: quicksand;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 82px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.navs {
  font-family: quicksand;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: quicksand
}

#left {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="head">Resume - Mathias Nicolajsen</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <a href="diagonaler.html"><strong><p class="navs" id="left">Projecter</p></strong></a>
  <strong><p class="navs">Omkring mig</p></strong>
</nav>
<p>Lavet af Mathias Nicolajsen</p>
```

Try to add `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `nav`with the following `CSS`

```
nav {
        background: #333333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 82px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. only with `text-align: center;` your problem will be solved.

```css
header {
  background: #444444;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: height 600ms 0s ease;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#head {
  font-family: quicksand;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 82px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.navs {
  font-family: quicksand;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: quicksand
}

#left {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="head">Resume - Mathias Nicolajsen</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <a href="diagonaler.html"><strong><p class="navs" id="left">Projecter</p></strong></a>
  <strong><p class="navs">Omkring mig</p></strong>
</nav>
<p>Lavet af Mathias Nicolajsen</p>
```

Comment: Did not see any difference between your answer and upvoted answer . that's why down voted.

Comment: Who ever down voting my answer , should know before giving that when I started answering it through the snippet , no answer was posted that time. If others also giving the same answer quickly than my post and if my post took some time for snippet ,does not mean that this is wrong answer or copied. When you down voted it, others will not consider its helpful. When I posted I saw others have the same answer , I can also down vote or can delete my answer. Instead I kept it open thinking it may help others. It's your call when you give vote them but should consider other conditions also.